# Skip converting entities while loading a yaml string (using PyYAML)

Tags: python, yaml

Is there a nice way to prevent the conversion of entities to python objects while loading a YAML string the yaml package? Particularily, I do not want the conversion of timestamp-strings to datetime objects.

Here is an example:

```
import yaml
yaml.load("""d: 2018-06-17\nn: 42""")
```

which gives

```
{'d': datetime.date(2018, 6, 17), 'n': 42}
```

but I would like to have

```
{'d': '2018-06-17', n: 42}
```

where the date string remains as the string and other types are converted. I do not want to change the input string, e.g., by specifying specific data types. Maybe there is an alternative YAML loader/parser package. I'm using python3.6 and PyYAML==3.12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyYAML interprets string as timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835322/pyyaml-interprets-string-as-timestamp)

Comment: this does not solve my problem. especially, the excepted answer suggests to modify the input, which i don't want

Comment: your likely option is modify the yaml reading result - convert datetime.date(2018, 6, 17) to string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YAML has several schema's and since you are using the default (unsafe) load in PyYAML you get all of the constructions to Python objects that it supports, including the one to `int` that you want, and the one to `datetime.time` that you don't want.

Since you want the integers to be converted, you cannot use the baseloader:

```
import yaml
data = yaml.load("""d: 2018-06-17\nn: 42""", Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
print(data)
```

as this gives strings everywhere:

```
{'d': '2018-06-17', 'n': '42'}
```

It is probably easiest to process the matched datetime objects as strings. In my `ruamel.yaml` library you can do so by using:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.constructor.yaml_constructors[u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp'] = \
   yaml.constructor.yaml_constructors[u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str']
data = yaml.load("""d: 2018-06-17\nn: 42""")
print(data)
```

if you only need to support the old YAML 1.1 specification, you can do the same in PyYAML:

```
import yaml
import yaml.constructor
yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.yaml_constructors[u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp'] = \
    yaml.constructor.SafeConstructor.yaml_constructors[u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str']

data = yaml.safe_load("""d: 2018-06-17\nn: 42""")
print(data)
```

both print:

```
{'d': '2018-06-17', 'n': 42}
```

Comment: If you both want "normal" loading and your non-interpretation of dates, then you cannot use the above solution, as the `yaml_constructors` is a class variable. In that case you need to subclass the `SafeLoader` and use its `.add_constructor` for all items but the `timestamp`

Comment: It is what I wanted. Thanks. Is there any good documentation regarding constrcutors in pyyaml?

Comment: @desiato Not really. I gather my "insights" analysing the code while developing the changes for round-tripping in ruamel.yaml.

Comment: @Anthon the suggested option with substituting timestamp constructor with string constructor gives a side effect. The value in output is single-quoted.
To overcome the issue I had to remove the constructor altogether: `yaml.constructor.yaml_constructors.pop(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp', None)`

Comment: @wheleph You should just use a different `YAML()` instance for oututting than for inputting if you muck around with the constructor for input.

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour is deeply rooted in the YAML specification, I tried `ruamel`, but the result is the same.

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from datetime import date

yaml=YAML(typ="unsafe")
assert yaml.load("""d: 2018-06-17\nn: 42""") == \
       {'d': date(2018, 6, 17), 'n': 42}
```

If I had this problem, I'd try convert the YAML import back with `.strftime('YYYY-MM-DD')` where needed.

Comment: The [YAML tag repository](http://yaml.org/type/) is mentioned in both the YAML 1.2 and the outdated YAML 1.1 specification that PyYAML follows. The `unsafe` and `safe` loaders implement all of these (and the unsafe one also language specific ones, that make it unsafe). You also have the BaseLoader, that makes everything into a string. So I am not sure that it is correct to write that this is "deeply rooted in the YAML specification".

Comment: @Anthon: what is a proper way of saying it? _default behaviour, unless using `BaseLoader` class_?

Comment: It is default behaviour for all Python YAML parser that I know. That not everything is a string, actually makes it useful, although PyYAML's `load()`  default is dangerous because it allows more than the tags from the tag repository. Most of the time smart object creation is what you want so that is what libraries provide, but that doesn't IMO make it *deeply rooted* in the specification, just the default for the implementations.