# Times from YML file printing wrong

Tags: python, time, printing, yaml, python-3.10

I have an `.yml` file which is my config. In this file I have defined two times which look like this:

```yaml
my-times:
    earliest_time: 17:00  #PM
    latest_time: 19:00  #PM
```

My code looks like this:

```py
conf: object = yaml.safe_load(open('myconfig.yml'))

earliest_time = str(conf['my-times']['earliest_time'])
latest_time = str(conf['my-times']['latest_time'])

print(earliest_time)
print(latest_time)
```

But when I'm in this time window and I want to print or use them in an `if`-statement, I got the following output:

```
0:00
1080
```

How do I print the second time in the code above normally, like how it is in the `.yml` file?

Comment: Are you sure the code is in the same direction with the .yml file? And is the path right?

Comment: just quote the times if you want them in string form. example: `earliest_time: "17:00"`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your yaml file:

```
my-times:
    earliest_time: "17:00"  #PM
    latest_time: "19:00"  #PM
```

This tells YAML that it is a literal string, and inhibits attempts to treat it as a numeric value.
Look at this post for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28835540/8961170

Answer (score 3):

The yaml loader is interpreting 17:00 as a time and returns the value as an integer representing the time in minutes. Thus 17:00 will be 1020 and 19:00 will be 1140

EDIT: Code sample to show how one might represent the acquired value in its original form:

```
import yaml

with open('myconfig.yml') as yml:
    conf = yaml.safe_load(yml)
    for k in ['earliest_time', 'latest_time']:
        e = conf['my-times'][k]
        h, m = divmod(e, 60)
        print(f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}')
```

**Output:**

```
17:00
19:00
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to calculate these values, or is there a table?

Comment: Converting minutes to hours and minutes is trivial. Try *divmod*