# Why is the first expression interpreted as an int, and the second as a string?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Using PyYaml

```py
import yaml

yaml.full_load(StringIO('a: 16:00:00'))
# {'a': 57600}
yaml.full_load(StringIO('a: 09:31:00'))
# {'a': '09:31:00'}
```

Why is there a difference in those behaviors?

Comment: Presumably because a leading zero trigger parsing as an octal number, but 09 is not a valid octal number, so YAML falls back to string. YAML has … issues. [Many issues](https://hitchdev.com/strictyaml/why-not/ordinary-yaml/). (Hang on, that's not it actually; octal parsing is *also* an issue, but for timestamp-y looking things YAML apparently never accepts a leading zero.)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165433/1126841) on a similar question. An older version of the YAML spec allowed for sexagesimal numbers (basically, base-60 values using `:` to separate "digits" instead of using distinct characters for each of the 60 values. PyYAML still attempts to parse them, though they were removed from YAML 1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of YAML supported sexagesimal (base 60) numbers, intended for use for things like times. Instead of adding additional digits (like hexadecimal uses 0-9 and A-F), it simply uses decimal numbers 0-59 separated by `:`s. `16:00:00` is thus equivalent to

```
16*(60**2) + 0*60 + 0 == 57600.
```

PyYAML apparently still uses this older YAML specification.

`09:30:00`, however, does not start with a valid decimal: a leading zero indicates an *octal* number, but `09` is not a valid octal number. Not being able to parse this as any kind of known number (octal, decimal, or sexagesimal), PyYAML falls back to a string.

YAML can represent timestamps, but only if they consist of a date and an optional timestamp. PyYAML parses such timestamps as `datetime.datetime` objects, as seems reasonable.

```
>>> yaml.full_load(StringIO('a:   2022-12-21T09:31:00'))
{a: datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 21, 9, 31)}
```

I referenced an answer in a comment, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165433/1126841, provided by the author of [another package](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) with does adhere to the YAML 1.2 specification, which will parse the value as a string, not a sexagesimal integer.

```
>>> from ruamel import yaml
>>> yaml.safe_load('a: 16:00:00')
{'a': '16:00:00'}
```

Comment: Even though PyYAML hasn't been updated since 2020, I really don't understand why it never added support for YAML 1.2, which came out in 2009. ruamel.yaml is definitely the way to go these days.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the heading `0` of `09:31:00`: remove it and you'll get your int value.